# Will a 110-220v to 12v converter work with a DC 12v 3w LED bulb?

Tags: voltage, led, transformer, converter, lightning

I'm planning to create some wall lights using these [LED bulbs](http://amzn.com/B0152NS25Y). Would I be able to just use any 110-220v to 12v converter to power this at home? I live in the US (120v).

I was thinking of using [this converter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/AC-DC-AC-110V-220V-to-DC12V-Isolation-Voltage-Converter-Step-Down-Power-Supply/181806067516?_trksid=p2047675.c100005.m1851&_trkparms=aid%3D222007%26algo%3DSIC.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20131003132420%26meid%3D4045bc14cfef407c94d9e52746654ab4%26pid%3D100005%26rk%3D3%26rkt%3D6%26sd%3D171573237894). Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is read the specs for the two things you show.  The LED lamps require 12 V, so that matches.  They are rated at 3 W, so the current is (3 W)/(12 V) = 250 mA.  That power supply can put out 350 mA, so one of them can power one lamp with some margin.  Again, this was all directly available in the data you linked to.

Comment: Thank you. In the converter spec it says 5w, so I wasn't sure. As a layman, I thought I'd make sure before messing around with these. Didn't want to have it work and end up with a fire a week later. :D